# Recent achievements & Recent inbox messages not shown on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, notification-bar

The Recent achievements & Recent inbox messages are not functioning in the Android app. They do function in the browser (on Android and otherwise) and in the iPhone app:

[image: Android app] [image: Android browser]

Comment: The recent inbox is working properly, unless I missed something else. OTOH, the recent achievements *never* have real-time reputation change on Android app (I can't tell if it's a [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request]).

Comment: @Andrew It's a bug report. Isn't the report clear, including even real screen captures? And I did not mention "real time". The recent achievements just don't show.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. What I meant, SE Android app never changes the *Achievement* icon to indicate if there's a reputation change, or badge (in other word, it's a static icon). So, from app's side, it's kind of a feature request (new feature to be implemented/added). Though, end-user might see it as a bug since it doesn't work the same way as on browser, which I can understand. That's why I thought it would be better to be retagged as [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @andrew Regardless of the classification, why doesn't it get fixed? Isn't the need obvious?

Comment: @bacon: If it isn't supposed to work, why is there a setting for a notification sound?

Comment: @zondo notification is for Inbox only, not (and never) for achievements, and it works for me through push notifications.

Comment: @bacon: Interesting.  It doesn't work for me.  I get no sound and the icon doesn't change.  I just need to remember to check every once in a while.